# Count result rows of table that is already counted and grouped by

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the results of counted and group by table results

Like I have a table, `a`:

```
id |name
1  |abc
2  |abc
3  |abc
4  |xyz
5  |xyz
```

My query is `SELECT COUNT(id) as count_id from a GROUP BY name`

...gives result :

```
count_id
3
2
```

I want to count this result's total row which is 2

So my query is `SELECT COUNT(SELECT COUNT(id) as count_id from a GROUP BY name) as maincount from a`

...but it gives me this error in `phpmyadmin`

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT count.....`

Comment: Andriy answer is working with your example? I just want to know.. Can you try once and let me know..

Comment: yes, Andriy answer is working and also working xQbert answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM a
```

Answer (score 2):

Sub-select would work though there likely is more elegant.

```
  Select count(*) from (SELECT COUNT(id) as count_id from a GROUP BY name) as b
```

Comment: +1 but you need to assign an alias to the subselect (MySQL requires it).